# Eloquent orm show ? instead values in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, where-clause

i have this function:

```
public function obtenerListaRegistros($where = NULL) {
    $bdObjeto = static::query();
    if ($where != NULL) {
        foreach ($where AS $w) {
            $bdObjeto->where($w['columna'], $w['condicional'], $w['valor']);
        }
    }

    return $bdObjeto->toSql();
}
```

the array $where is similar to:

```
array(
    0 => array(
       'columna' => 'deleted'
       'condicional' => '=',
       'valor' => 0
    )
);
```

but it returns **select * from `usuario` where `delected` = ?** instead **select * from `usuario` where `deleted` = 0** ...

I had tried without the foreach but it still showing the "?" and the ->get() function but this returns all rows...

thanks in advance

Comment: Just a hint: use empty array as default value `($where = [])` and you can get rid of this `if ($where != NULL)` condition. Apart from that, @lukasgeiter gave you the answer, read about `PDO` for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Laravel uses *bindings* to insert values into the query to avoid SQL injection. The `?`s will be replaced with the actual values when the query is run.